# How to add "Not" in endswith tag of Transaction search in Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-sdk

I am building a query in splunk to filter logs that start with `INFO:__main__:TABLE:` and does "NOT" endswith `INFO:__main__: Done`
I want all the transactions that do not log `Done` in the end. `!`/ `Not` does not seem to work.

Part of the query I am stuck with:

```
| rex field=log "INFO:__main__:TABLE: (?<table_name>[A-Za-z_]*)" 
| transaction container_name startswith="INFO:__main__:TABLE:" endswith="INFO:__main__: Done"
```

The current query will give me the transactions that terminated correctly/with Done status. I am interested in the one with `NOT "DONE"` status.

I want something like:

```
| transaction container_name startswith="INFO:__main__:TABLE:" endswith!="INFO:__main__: Done"
```

Answer (score 3):

As you've discovered, the `transaction` command's `endwith` option does not support NOT.  It wouldn't make a lot of sense.  What's more, it would make an inefficient command even more inefficient since negative searches in Splunk are more costly than positive searches.

You'll need to find a different way to define a transaction or use a different command.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex's in an `eval` statement, which is valid for `startswith`. Here's an example:

```
... | transaction field startswith="xyz" endswith=eval(match(_raw, "\d\d\s+start"))
```

Use regex according to your requirement.

Comment: tannu, how about a text